# Add Leaflet GeoJSON layers from GeoServer to an Array using a Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, leaflet

I'm trying to add GeoJSON layers to an array using a loop, and then showing them on my map.

My goal is to have a variable like this: scenario_json[1] = layer1, scenario_json[2] = layer2, etc...

```
    myURL = [
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/jonquiere_local/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=jonquiere_local:buildings_phase1&maxFeatures=400&maxFeatures=400&outputFormat=json&format_options=callback:getJson",
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/jonquiere_local/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=jonquiere_local:buildings_phase2&maxFeatures=400&outputFormat=json&format_options=callback:getJson",
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/jonquiere_local/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=jonquiere_local:buildings_phase3&maxFeatures=400&outputFormat=json&format_options=callback:getJson"
];


$.getScript('src/leaflet.js');

for(i=0;i<=myURL.length;i++){

    var scenario_json = {};
    scenario_json[i] = new L.GeoJSON();

    function getJson(data){
        console.log(data)
        scenario_json[i].addData(data); 
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: myURL[i],
        jsonp: false,
        dataType: "json",
        jsonpCallback: "getJson",
        success: getJson
    })
};
```

I am getting this response in my console:

```
Object {readyState: 1}
VM3689:10 Object {type: "FeatureCollection", totalFeatures: 386, features: Array[386], crs: Object}
VM3689:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addData' of undefinedgetJson @ VM3689:11c @ jquery.min.js:3p.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:3k @ jquery.min.js:5r @ jquery.min.js:5
VM3689:10 Object {type: "FeatureCollection", totalFeatures: 377, features: Array[377], crs: Object}
VM3689:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addData' of undefined
```

Any idea why it doesn't work ?

Thanks

Comment: In your `$.ajax` settings, does changing `jsonpCallbat` to `jsonpCallback` fix the response?

Comment: Oh, little error here but it doesn't fix the problem... I edit the main post. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that `scenario_json` doesn't exist in the context of the `getJson` callback.

I'm unsure as to why you're using JSONP since it's an old workaround for making crossdomain requests. You don't need that since you're working from localhost/same domain at the moment. You could try to just use plain XHR with JSON instead of JSONP.

Remove the `formatOptions` from your URL's:

```
myURL = [
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/jonquiere_local/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=jonquiere_local:buildings_phase1&maxFeatures=400&maxFeatures=400&outputFormat=json",
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/jonquiere_local/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=jonquiere_local:buildings_phase2&maxFeatures=400&outputFormat=json",
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/jonquiere_local/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=jonquiere_local:buildings_phase3&maxFeatures=400&outputFormat=json"
];
```

Switch to `$.getJSON`:

```
for (i = 0; i <= myURL.length; i++) {

    var scenario_json = {};

    $.getJSON(myURL[i], function (data) {
        scenario_json[i] = new L.GeoJSON(data);
    }).done(function () {
        console.log('$.getJSON Done!');
    }).fail(function () {
        console.log('$.getJSON Fail!');
    });
}
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fNf9CDTBCCsj3cavVjJY?p=preview

PS. If you ever run into crossdomain issues you can simple solve it by enabling CORS on your GeoServer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I don't get the error anymore, but it looks like only the scenario_json[4] gets data in it. scenario_json[1], [2] and [3] are undefined. Any idea why ?

Comment: Can you verify the responses are correct in the networktab of your developertools? Do they actually contain the data you expect? You can validate the return strings on http://geojsonlint.com/ Draw back of `$.getJSON` is that it fails silently when the return isn't proper JSON. I'll edit my answer and add a failure routine.

Comment: The function with the fail routine is working fine, I don't get any Fail alert in the routine, but the first 3 arrays of the variable are still empty... The 3 JSON that I get in the response are working fine too when tested on the website.

Comment: Spotted one error but it wasn't critical, changed `<=` to `<` in the `for` loop. But it shouldn't fail on that. Added a working example to my answer. Kind of stumped as to why you're not getting proper results.

Comment: I added the ".addTo(map)" and the layers are showing on my map as a unique layer. But even with your code if you type "layers[1] or layers[2]" in the console it shows undefined, but not for layer[3]. Your code was working fine I just missed that.

But, I think i wasn't clear with my first question. I want to use the array to load multiple geoJson but as separate layers(which will be integrated in a layer switcher). My first idea was to try to increment variable names at each iteration but It looks like using an array was a more common practice. However, I don't know if it can do the job

Comment: Great that you've got it working so far. If love to help you out further but it's best if you post a new question regarding current problems with the relevant code/info because this is getting awefully cluttered. Tip, you don't have to store them in an array first. You could initialize your layer control first: `var lc = new L.Control.Layers` and then in your loop add the layers to it: `var layer = new L.GeoJSON(data).addTo(map); lc.addOverlay(layer, 'Layer ' + i)` see: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-addoverlay

Comment: Hi again, I modified the "scenario_json[i] = new L.GeoJSON(data);", scenario_json[i++] = new L.GeoJSON(data); and now I can access the three layers, but I can access them using scenario_json[3], scenario_json[4] and scenario_json[5]. Any idea why it isn't [1] [2] and [3] ?

Comment: As said, since this is a completely different question than you started out with and it's getting terribly cluttered it's best to just post a new question. Comments aren't meant/suited for this. Just post a new question, with your current code and the relevant info. I'll keep an eye out.