# Stock and control Leaflet GeoJSON layers in a variable/object with incrementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, openlayers

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064899/add-leaflet-geojson-layers-from-geoserver-to-an-array-using-a-javascript-loop), I'm trying to stock the geoJson layers in a variable using a javascript loop and then using them on my map with a layer control panel. Here's my code:

```
myURL = [
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/jonquiere_local/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=jonquiere_local:buildings_phase1&maxFeatures=400&outputFormat=json",
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/jonquiere_local/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=jonquiere_local:buildings_phase2&maxFeatures=400&outputFormat=json",
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/jonquiere_local/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=jonquiere_local:scenario1&maxFeatures=400&outputFormat=json"
];

lc = new L.control.layers();    

for (i = 0; i < myURL.length; i++) {

    var scenario_json = {};

    $.getJSON(myURL[i], function (data) {
        scenario_json[i++] = new L.GeoJSON(data).addTo(map);
    }).done(function () {
        console.log('$.getJSON Done!');
    }).fail(function () {
        console.log('$.getJSON Fail!');
    });

    lc.addOverlay(scenario_json, "Layer " + i);

};

lc.addTo(map);
```

(Problem #1): The resulting `scenario_json` variable incrementation is not right. The GeoJSON layers are stocked in `scenario_json[3]`, `scenario_json[4]` and `scenario_json[5]` and I have no idea why.

(Problem #2): I'm trying to make the 3 layers selectable independently by a layer controller. The layer control button appears on the map, but if I hover over it, it disappear and no layer are shown, and again, I don't know why.

Someone have any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1: All three requests are fired (almost) instantly. By the time the first request is actually resolved, the `i` variable holds the last value of the iteration: `3`. Solution, don't use an object but an array and it will take care of the count for you.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myURL.length; i++) {

    var scenario_json = [];

    $.getJSON(myURL[i], function (data) {
        scenario_json.push(new L.GeoJSON(data).addTo(map));
    });

};
```

Problem 2: You forgot use the `addTo` method of `L.Control.Layers` which actually adds the control the map: `new L.Control.Layers().addTo(map);`

Also, you'll need to call `addOverlay` in the callback of `$.getJSON`, so it get executed once the layer is ready, now it's called immediately, before your request is resolved:

```
var lc = new L.Control.Layers().addTo(map);

for (var i = 0; i < myURL.length; i++) {

    var scenario_json = [];

    $.getJSON(myURL[i], function (data) {

        var layer = new L.GeoJSON(data).addTo(map);
        scenario_json.push(layer);
        lc.addOverlay(layer, 'Layer ' + scenario_json.length);

    });

};
```

Complete solution on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/M1CxWoyHUjc85zRpmtsS?p=preview

On a sidenote. It's considered best practice to declare variables with the `var` keyword. At the moment your not doing that for `myURL`, `lc` and `i`

Comment: Works fine, thanks again for your help, it's very appreciated !